# tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession arguments

Tags: python, session, tensorflow, distributed-computing, fault-tolerance

what arguments does `config=None` take in [tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/train/distributed_execution#MonitoredTrainingSession)?. How can I specify the master node (at for eg `localhost:2222`) with the proper syntax?

Below is is the error I am encountering when i use `config = 'grpc://localhost:2222'` :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "add_1.py", line 36, in <module>
    scaffold=None, hooks=[saver_hook, summary_hook], chief_only_hooks=None, save_checkpoint_secs=10, save_summaries_steps=None, config='grpc://localhost:2222') as sess:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 289, in MonitoredTrainingSession
    return MonitoredSession(session_creator=session_creator, hooks=hooks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 447, in __init__
    self._sess = _RecoverableSession(self._coordinated_creator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 618, in __init__
    _WrappedSession.__init__(self, self._sess_creator.create_session())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 505, in create_session
    self.tf_sess = self._session_creator.create_session()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 341, in create_session
    init_fn=self._scaffold.init_fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py", line 227, in prepare_session
    config=config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py", line 153, in _restore_checkpoint
    sess = session.Session(self._target, graph=self._graph, config=config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1186, in __init__
    super(Session, self).__init__(target, graph, config=config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 540, in __init__
    % type(config))
TypeError: config must be a tf.ConfigProto, but got <type 'str'>
Exception AttributeError: "'Session' object has no attribute '_session'" in <bound method Session.__del__ of <tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x7fc540937ed0>> ignored
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `config` argument to [`tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/train/distributed_execution#MonitoredTrainingSession) takes a [`tf.ConfigProto`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d3822f06ca4440bf33d9034022e81ba4620f99c1/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto#L158) protocol buffer message.

It looks like you should actually pass your argument (`"grpc://localhost:2222"`) as the `master` argument, which takes the same values as the `target` argument to the [`tf.Session` initializer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/client/session_management#Session.__init__): e.g. `""` means "in-process runtime", and `"grpc://localhost:2222"` means "the gRPC-based `tf.train.Server` listening on `localhost:2222`.

Comment: The master config was incomplete. Thanks. Current `config=None`